# nginx auth_basic time limitation

Tags: authentication, nginx

I'm protecting my dev server using nginx and the `auth_basic` module, but I can't seem to find a way to specify the interval at which the 'authentication' expires.

I would like to be able to force nginx to ask for the password say every 6 hours. Is there a way to do that? If not, what is an acceptable workaround?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's probably not possible. There doesn't seem to be any documentation on the [nginx HttpAuthBasicModule page](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpAuthBasicModule#auth_basic) to suggest that you can timeout Basic HTTP authentication.

The [HTTP specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1945#section-11) for `Authorization` headers also does not specify a timeout mechanism. I don't expect you'll be able to rely on basic authentication if you need timeouts, unless you're also fronting a web application.

If you're fronting a web application, you could maintain a session in a cookie and time out the session after a period of inactivity. When the session timeout finishes, use your web application to send the following headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
WWW-Authenticate: Basic Realm="MyApp"
```

That will prompt the browser to ask for credentials again. If you need access to the user's identity in your web application, you *should* find it in the `REMOTE_USER` CGI environment variable.

To serve static assets efficiently using this technique, `XSendfile` [might be useful](http://wiki.nginx.org/XSendfile).

Comment: CGI does not provide `REMOTE_USER` automatically. You can set it by `fastcgi_param REMOTE_USER $remote_user;`.

Comment: This method isn't foolproof. Upon being re-prompted, if you click "Cancel" and refresh the page, you will be logged in again.

Answer (score 7):

If you are still looking for solution to this issue, I believe HttpAuthDigestModule is what you are looking for.

I just found it today while surfing the Internet.

Here are the links:

http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpAuthDigestModule

https://github.com/samizdatco/nginx-http-auth-digest

Hopefully it helps you.