# Celery flower with apache2 reverse proxy ssl handshake fails for websocket

Tags: apache, ssl, websocket, flower, proxytunnel

I am trying to setup a reverse proxy for flower behind apache2 as outlined in this post [Celery Flower Security in Production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19689510/celery-flower-security-in-production).

Https pageloads from flower work just fine through the proxy, but the websocket it opens to update the dashboard does not - the ssl handshake fails and no response is returned.  I am using apache2 2.2.22 on ubuntu 12.04 and I have added mod_proxy_wstunnel via a commonly used patch in order to tunnel the websocket connection.  I am running flower through supervisord on 127.0.0.1:5555.

Here is the relevant portion of my apache .conf

```
SSLProxyEngine On
SSLProxyVerify none

ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPass /update-dashboard wss://127.0.0.1:5555/update-dashboard
ProxyPassReverse /update-dashboard wss://127.0.0.1:5555/update-dashboard

ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:5555/
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:5555/
<Proxy  *>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Proxy>
```

Here is the request after it eventually times out

```
"GET /update-dashboard HTTP/1.1"
 500 419 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML,     like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.124 Safari/537.36"
```

Here is the output from the apache2 error log

```
[Fri Jun 12 16:44:28 2015] [info] Initial (No.1) HTTPS request received for child 195 (server demoflower.eatthismuch.com:80)
[Fri Jun 12 16:44:28 2015] [debug] mod_proxy_wstunnel.c(377): [client 71.189.228.118] canonicalising URL //127.0.0.1:5555/update-dashboard
[Fri Jun 12 16:44:28 2015] [debug] proxy_util.c(1509): [client 71.189.228.118] proxy: wss: found worker wss://127.0.0.1:5555/update-dashboard for wss://127.0.0.1:5555/update-dashboard
[Fri Jun 12 16:44:28 2015] [debug] mod_proxy.c(1020): Running scheme wss handler (attempt 0)
[Fri Jun 12 16:44:28 2015] [debug] mod_proxy_http.c(1978): proxy: HTTP: declining URL wss://127.0.0.1:5555/update-dashboard
[Fri Jun 12 16:44:28 2015] [debug] mod_proxy_wstunnel.c(659): [client 71.189.228.118] AH02451: serving URL wss://127.0.0.1:5555/update-dashboard
[Fri Jun 12 16:44:28 2015] [debug] proxy_util.c(2014): proxy: WSS: has acquired connection for (127.0.0.1)
[Fri Jun 12 16:44:28 2015] [debug] proxy_util.c(2070): proxy: connecting wss://127.0.0.1:5555/update-dashboard to 127.0.0.1:5555
[Fri Jun 12 16:44:28 2015] [debug] proxy_util.c(2196): proxy: connected /update-dashboard to 127.0.0.1:5555
[Fri Jun 12 16:44:28 2015] [debug] proxy_util.c(2447): proxy: WSS: fam 2 socket created to connect to 127.0.0.1
[Fri Jun 12 16:44:28 2015] [debug] proxy_util.c(2579): proxy: WSS: connection complete to 127.0.0.1:5555 (127.0.0.1)
[Fri Jun 12 16:44:28 2015] [info] [client 127.0.0.1] Connection to child 0 established (server demoflower.eatthismuch.com:80)
[Fri Jun 12 16:44:28 2015] [info] Seeding PRNG with 656 bytes of entropy
[Fri Jun 12 16:44:28 2015] [debug] mod_proxy_wstunnel.c(518): [client 71.189.228.118] sending request
[Fri Jun 12 16:44:28 2015] [debug] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1819): OpenSSL: Handshake: start
[Fri Jun 12 16:44:28 2015] [debug] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1827): OpenSSL: Loop: before/connect initialization
[Fri Jun 12 16:44:28 2015] [debug] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1827): OpenSSL: Loop: unknown state
[Fri Jun 12 16:44:32 2015] [debug] ssl_engine_io.c(1908): OpenSSL: I/O error, 5 bytes expected to read on BIO#7f0b6c001650 [mem: 7f0b68006f83]
[Fri Jun 12 16:44:32 2015] [debug] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1837): OpenSSL: Write: SSL negotiation finished successfully
[Fri Jun 12 16:44:32 2015] [debug] ssl_engine_io.c(1908): OpenSSL: I/O error, 5 bytes expected to read on BIO#7f0b60001650 [mem: 7f0b60006f83]
[Fri Jun 12 16:44:32 2015] [debug] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1837): OpenSSL: Write: SSL negotiation finished successfully
[Fri Jun 12 13:44:32 2015] [debug] ssl_engine_io.c(1908): OpenSSL: I/O error, 5 bytes expected to read on BIO#7f0b70001650 [mem: 7f0b70006f83]
[Fri Jun 12 13:44:32 2015] [debug] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1837): OpenSSL: Write: SSL negotiation finished successfully
[Fri Jun 12 16:44:32 2015] [debug] ssl_engine_io.c(1908): OpenSSL: I/O error, 5 bytes expected to read on BIO#7f0b6c001650 [mem: 7f0b70006f83]
[Fri Jun 12 16:44:32 2015] [debug] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1837): OpenSSL: Write: SSL negotiation finished successfully
[Fri Jun 12 16:44:32 2015] [debug] ssl_engine_io.c(1908): OpenSSL: I/O error, 5 bytes expected to read on BIO#7f0b60001650 [mem: 7f0b70006f83]
[Fri Jun 12 16:44:32 2015] [debug] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1837): OpenSSL: Write: SSL negotiation finished successfully
[Fri Jun 12 16:44:32 2015] [debug] ssl_engine_io.c(1908): OpenSSL: I/O error, 5 bytes expected to read on BIO#7f0b64001650 [mem: 7f0b70006f83]
[Fri Jun 12 16:44:32 2015] [debug] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1837): OpenSSL: Write: SSL negotiation finished successfully
```

Any ideas what might be going wrong?  I've tried a lot of different apache2 settings to no avail.  Thanks for reading!

Comment: Did you manage to solve the "declining URL" problem?

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar apache config file and it was not working correctly and I saw the OpenSSL error 5 bytes expected message.

I added the following:

```
ProxyPreserveHost On
```

and now the application works correctly.
I still see the OpenSSL error, but it does not appear to be a problem.

Note the declining http URL is just the normal operation of `mod_proxy` trying all lower level proxy modules in a specified order until it finds one that matches.

Also I am using `ws:` protocol not `wss:` to talk to Tomcat 8 backend.